# Installing Java 8 on cloud9

Tags: java-8, cloud9-ide

I'm trying to install java 8 on cloud9 through the webupd8 PPA. So I'm adding the repository

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
```

Next I do the update and finally when I run the command

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

I get the error

```
E: Unable to locate package oracle-java8-installer
```

Any ideas how can I get through that and istall java 8 on cloud9?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the two following lines to your file `/etc/apt/sources.list` (which you can create if it does not exist)

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main
```

Then run `sudo apt-get update`, and you should be able to install `oracle-java8-installer`.

This basically does the `add-apt-repository` manually. I suspect the issue is due to the fact that the default source files `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*` are mounted as read-only (see for instance [this topic](https://community.c9.io/t/read-only-file-system-etc-apt-sources-list-d-c9-list/4067) on Cloud9 community)

Answer (score 7):

As noted by christophetd, I completed the following steps and everything installed without issue:

`$ sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list`

Add the following lines of code to the file:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main
```

`$ sudo apt-get update`

`$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java`

`$ sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer`

`$ java -version`

```
java version "1.8.0_101"
```